# Document title not set on upload

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am uploading a file to a SharePoint list using Copy web service. I am also updating the Title field of the uploaded file using below code.

```
 FieldInformation obj = new FieldInformation();
        obj.DisplayName = "Title";
        obj.InternalName = "Title";
        obj.Type = FieldType.Text;
        obj.Value = "Test Title 1";
```

The web service is uploading the file but it does not update the title field. Title field remains same as the actual file name and does not update to 'Test title 1'.

Comment: i think it should be obj.DisplayName = "Test Title 1";

Comment: Then it should change the title to Title bt its changing it to file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I was missing an additional line.

```
copyservice.FieldInformation[] info = { obj };
```